# JavaFX chat container with styled text for messages, authors, files, etc

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a chat application in Java using JavaFX.

I am now trying to add the chat window with messages being added all the time in a formatted way. How would I do this? I thought about using a `WebView` but I think using static HTML appending new code all the time wouldn't be the right thing to do. Is there any other control I should be aware of?

The "formatted way" means different styles for the author, the message body, support for hyperlinks and embedded images.

Thank you.

Comment: i don't think that standard components have another suited for you component.

Comment: How about using a ListView ?